# Creating map or converting to GeoTIFF, Bufr format?

Tags: convert, geotiff-tiff

I'm trying to work with spatial data saved in [WMO BUFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BUFR) format (.buf extension). I need to cut data to my extent, create map and calculate spatial statistics.

I'm aware that two tools are able to open BUFR files:

- Metview (but only RedHat-based packages are available and compiling it from the source is real pain)
- Grads (but to open it, one needs to prepare ctl description file for each bufr),
  but none of them (?) is able to export BUFR to GeoTIFF/other GIS format.

Comment: maybe this helps? https://github.com/pytroll/python-bufr

Comment: @toms I've tried to use this library, but without success. According to documentation (https://github.com/pytroll/python-bufr/blob/master/doc/source/usage-bufr.rst) I should simply use _import bufr_ and then _bufr.BUFRFile_ to point to BUFR file...but I receive an error message - seems there is no _BUFRFile_ method in bufr module.

Comment: not a good sign if they document methods that don't exist - I've never used it myself, maybe you could file an issue? Not sure how actively they are supporting/developing.

Answer (score 1):

The [wikipedia page for the BUFR format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BUFR) suggests some libraries that can be used to convert the data.  (but some of the links seem to be outdated)

Perhaps some of those libraries could be used to convert the data to a desired format (or to some other format that can then be converted to Geotiff/others using [GDAL/OGR](http://gdal.org/))?